# Converting bash to ksh

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

My current shell is bash and I want to convert to ksh. I tried to convert through chsh or ypchsh but dont have permission to convert. So I tried to convert using .bash_profile as below

```
$vi .bash_profile
ksh
. ./.profile .
```

On reopening the putty, .bash_profile runs which changes to ksh, but the alias in .profile are not getting resolved.

Comment: No i dont have permission to edit the /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check following answer and use login SHELL

```
ksh --login
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072913/how-to-manually-start-interactive-ksh-and-have-it-execute-home-profile-on-sta

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in your example `.profile` won't be sourced until you exit `ksh`. That's the way shell works.

I tried to do on my local machine the following:

```
$ cat /home/test/.profile
exec ksh

$ cat ~/.kshrc
echo "commands you need in ksh"
```

As profile is read only once on a login, it seems to be working. Whenever I login as a user, I've `ksh` as a shell. Didn't check it with `tmux` or `screen` though.

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9667 pts/1    00:00:00 ksh
 9675 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Note, that I use `exec ksh` over simple invoke `ksh`, so you'll have just `ksh` which replaced `bash` instead of `ksh` running as a child of `bash`.

In any way, I advise to ask sysadmin or whoever has the grant to update the settings in /etc/passwd to do so. It might help you to avoid unexpected issues with inheritance of some settings from bash you might not face when you directly invoke ksh.